# When a div is hidden using jQuery toggle, add/change CSS using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an anchor with class "hide-btn1". When it is clicked I want the following to happen:

1. rcol-content hides(toggles) and the text changes(toggles) into from Hide to show
2. #container width should increase to value "2038px"
3. table.status-table width should increase to "1669px"

In order to achieve all this I have come up with this code so far, but I dont know how to move forward from here:

```
$('.hide-btn1').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).text(function(i,v) {
           return v === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
     });
});
```

**Edit:** 
Added HTML Code as requested:

```
<div id="container">
   <a class="hide-btn1">Hide</a>

   <div class="rcol-content">
        <p>This would be included in the right column</p>

   </div>
   <table class="status-table>
     <tr>
       <th>Heading</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Table Data</td>
     </tr>
   </table>

</div><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle to check what you have so far.

Comment: This is not enough information. Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) as @SubashSelvaraj asks.

Comment: Have you notice that there's no `rcol-content`, `#container`, or `table.status-table` on the code you provided? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: just added HTML code as requested.

Answer (score 2):

I am attempting to provide something based on what you have provided. Quick way is:

```
$('a.hide-btn1').click(function(){
    $('.rcol-content').toggle();
    $('#container').css('width','2038px');
    $('table.status-table').css('width','1669px');
});
```

However, I would recommend just adding a class with css below the default styles in the stylesheet. Using JS to generate css is not good practice.

```
$('a.hide-btn1').click(function(){
    $('.rcol-content').toggle();
    $('#container').addClass('newClassOne');
    $('table.status-table').addClass('newClassTwo');
});
```

Hope this helps. But, like the other comments have said, you should have a fiddle or codepen to better describe your desired outcome. Good luck.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v40u9ojt/)